# Is it possible to group multiple collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

so I'm working with a database that has multiple collections and some of the data overlaps in the collection . In particular I have a collection called app-launches which contains a field called userId and one called users where the _id of a particular object is actually the same as the userId in app-launches. Is it possible to group the two collections together so I can analyze the data? Or maybe match the the userId in app-launches with the _id in users?

Comment: What are your collections? Do the document reside in the same collection? Do you want the result to be grouped, or are you talking about melting the documents?

Comment: Now that you ask that I guess I asked the question wrong, app-launches and users are two separate collections. But the _id in users is a key that corresponds with the userId key in app-launches.

Comment: Seems like you need to do a little RTFM. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/

Answer (score 1):

There is no definit answer for your question Jeffrey and none of the experts here can tell you to choose which technique  over other  just by having this information.

After going through various web pages over internet and mongo documentation and understanding the design patterns used in Mongo over a period of time, How I would design it depends on few things which I can try explaining it here in short.

1. if you have a **One-To-One** relation then always prefer to choose Embedding over Linking. e.g. User and its address (assuming user has only one address) thus you can utilize the atomicity (without worrying about transactions) as well easily fetch the records without too and fro to bring other information as in the case of Linking (like in DBRef)
2. If you have **One-To-Many** relation then you need to consider whether you can do the stuff by using Embedding (prefer this as explained the benefits in point 1). However, embedding would help you if you always want the information altogether e.g. Post/Comments where your requirement is to get the post and all of its comments by postId let say. But think of a situation where you need to get all the comments (and it related posts) which contains some specific tags in comments. in this case you should prefer Linking Because if you go via Embedding route then you would end up getting all the collection of comments for a post and you have to filter the desired comments.
3. for a **Many-To-Many** relations I would prefer two separate entities as well another collection for linking them e.g. Product-Category.

-$